# Principal component analysis plot in R

Tags: r, pca

I need a PCA plot which shows whether and how the data clusters by the populations (AFR_ACB, AFR_ASW,etc.) I also need different colours for each population and a legend for the population colours. It would also be good if I could add a frame for all African populations together, American populations, Asians and Europeans as my real data consists of all these population

I have data in the following format in a csv (TLR9.csv) file which I created from my result files. In reality, there are 26 columns (26 populations) and 1522 rows.

```
nuc_pos AFR_ACB AFR_ASW AMR_PUR AMR_PEL EAS_CHS EAS_JPN EUR_FIN EUR_CEU AMR_MXL AMR_PEL AMR_PUR EAS_CDX  EAS_CHB  EAS_CHS
42809473    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00971 0
42809498    0.01042 0   0.0201  0.00885 0   0.03488 0.00926 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42809524    0   0   0   0   0.0201  0   0.00926 0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42809625    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.08192 0.01563 0.02339 0.02857 0   0   0
42809638    0   0   0   0.00885 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42809715    0.30628 0.20485 0.34743 0.36531 0.19059 0.36199 0.34729 0.02116 0.01563 0   0.06536 0   0   0
42809846    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.00971 0.00952
42809910    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0.01176 0   0   0   0
42809911    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42809964    0.30628 0.20485 0.34743 0.36531 0.20638 0.38016 0.35241 0.02116 0.01563 0   0.06536 0   0   0
42810034    0.30628 0.20485 0.34743 0.36531 0.19059 0.34918 0.34729 0.02116 0.01563 0   0.06536 0   0   0
42810082    0   0   0   0   0   0.02339 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42810098    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42810103    0   0   0   0   0.0101  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42810184    0   0   0   0   0.03    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
42810189    0.30628 0.20485 0.34743 0.36531 0.19853 0.34918 0.34729 0.02116 0.01563 0   0.06536 0   0   0
42810233    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I have made a PCA plot using the following code:

```
df <- read.csv('TLR9.csv')
pca_res <- prcomp(df, scale. = TRUE)
autoplot(pca_res, data = df, loadings = TRUE, loadings.label = TRUE, frame = TRUE, label = TRUE, shape = FALSE, label.size = 2, loadings.label.size = 3)
```

[image: This is my scatterplot]

Is the input file format correct for this type of analysis? Is it also right to take all 26 populations as principal component?

I have tried other R packages where the tutorials are better explained how to make a PCA on R, but they are not compatible with the R version I have. So, I tried this one and it works but I am not sure the output is the way it should be.

This is my first time doing pca and I am not very familiar with R. Any help would be most appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does my answer respond to your question?

Comment: Hi Andy. I am sorry but I was not able to test the code at all. I tried installing the FactoMineR package but I was having the following error:

Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘FactoMineR’ had non-zero exit status

The downloaded source packages are in
 ‘/tmp/RtmpHtrBPj/downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: In .rs.normalizePath(defaultLibraryPath) :
  path[1]="/home/aahm/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0": No such file or directory
2: In .rs.normalizePath(libPaths) :
  path[1]="/home/aahm/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0": No such file or directory.

Comment: I made a search why I was having this and I found somewhere that FactoMineR cannot be used with R version 3.4. I uninstalled R and reinstalled version 3.5 but I am having problems with this too. So, I did this:

sudo apt --fix-broken install
sudo apt autoremove
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get install r-base-dev

And I find myself again with the same problem. Can you suggest another package that would work with version 3.4 of R? Thanks.

Comment: it seems you may be running a very old version of R (even 3.5 is old).  Try deleting R again, go to the website link below, update to the latest version, and try again.  I am running R version 4.0.2 (2020-06-22)

https://www.r-project.org/

Comment: I have reinstalled R 4.0.3 on my pc but I still cannot install the package. I am getting the following error:
ERROR: dependency ‘rio’ is not available for package ‘car’

* removing ‘/home/aahm/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/4.0/car’

* installing *source* package ‘shiny’ ...

** package ‘shiny’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

** using staged installation
** R
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
*** copying figures
** testing if installed package keeps a record of temporary installation path
* DONE (shiny

Comment: I have tried installing the package factorexta as well but I get an error with it too.

Comment: OK, that's interesting, I am unaware of that issue. I would suggest posting a new question on this forum, about the error you are getting when trying to install the FactoMineR package, informing people if you use Mac, PC, or Linux, and I am sure someone could solve your issue.

Comment: Thanks Andy. I just resoved it by installing libcurl then reinstalling FactoMineR. Its working fine and I'm testing the code now Finally.

Comment: great. If my code works, please up vote my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

First, I cannot use your dataset, since you did not make it available to us.  So I made one available down below

First, this is very easily done in the `library(FactoMineR)`.

Load data frame

```
df <- read.table("https://pastebin.com/raw/6aukL6YW", header=T)

library(FactoMineR) # load package

names(df) notice I have one column called "treatment", the others are columns filled with data
```

Run the PCA

```
x <- PCA(df,quali.sup=1) # the quali.sup= is referring to "which column do you want to refer to as a category (and each category is automatically assigned a color), in your case, this would be "population"
```

you can also make a scatterplot with the `plot.PCA()` command directly integrated in the FactoMineR package

```
plot.PCA(x, axes=c(1, 2), cex=1,choix="ind", habillage=1) # habillage is referring the which column you want to treat as a factor, and it also will assign different colors, (again in your case, "population
 and this plot automatically adds a legend
```

Finally, you can make a plot which could tell you which variable is causing the most variation in your data set , again, with `plot.PCA()`

```
plot.PCA(x, choix='var',select='contrib 2') # top 2 contributors of variation, the rest are not shown in bold, could do 5, 10, etc..
```

And there you go...

Comment: Hi Andy. Thanks a lot for the help! I have installed the FactoMineR package and I get the following message when I run my script:
 The downloaded source packages are in '/tmp/RtmpKcLvrC/downloaded_packages’
> source('~/SoftMaker/Documents/Aahm/pca_test.R')
Error in library(FactoMineR) : there is no package called ‘FactoMineR’
> View (df)

Comment: That was actually useful Andy. Again thanks!

Comment: glad I could help @ahusnoo :)

Comment: How do I plot 5 principal components on the graph? I tried changing plot.PCA(res.pca, axes=c(1,2), cex=1,choix="ind", habillage=1) to plot.PCA(res.pca, axes=c(1,5), cex=1,choix="ind", habillage=1) but I get the following error: Error in res.pca$ind$coord[, axes, drop = FALSE] : 
  subscript out of bounds

Comment: I am not sure I follow.  But to make a brief answer, it doesn't matter how many variables you have on the graph, you can have 5, you can have 50, the PCA can take that all into consideration.  If you have a way of sharing your dataset, I could probably figure it out.  You could use pastebin.com to share your dataset with me if you'd like

Comment: Thanks again. Here is the link to the dataset: https://pastebin.com/DnSAAyA1

Comment: please paste ONLY the data in pastebin.  you seemed to have added a lot of information. 

just open your datasheet in whatever program you use (excel, text editor..), select all, copy, and paste that directly into pastebin and share the link here.